# Get Global Descriptor Table under Linux

Tags: linux

i want to know if there is any method to retrieve GDT informations under Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get/set LDTs using the function `modify_ldt` (not a real function but a `syscall`, so you'll have to call it manually).

But for the GDT I don't know. But anyway, AFAIK, the GDT is not changed once the system is booted, so you can read it from the source ;-).